# Is it a usage of participal phrase in this sentence

Tags: past-perfect, participles

Someone wrote:

> When I came, the students split into teams, **sat** at a table and the teacher was asking questions while showing the students sheets with four answers.

I changed it into:

> When I came, the students had already split up into teams, **sitting** at different tables and the teacher was asking questions while giving each team papers with four answers **on them**.

I thought because they were in a sitting position, I can use "sitting" instead of "sat", though I don't know the related grammar (if it is valid), I thought it can be a usage of participial phrase.

Comment: To me _on them_ is neither natural nor needed.

Comment: *were sitting* sounds more natural to me